# I am not able to run flutter on my pc with an emulator

Tags: flutter

Every time i try to run in a web mode it says "There is some kind of module missing". and not tells what the module is.

I expected it to come in a web browser or another method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you might be using windows while running the code, please try selecting chrome.

[Check here to select the option for device change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD3YF.png)

[Select chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRQ4.png)

or else check for the error message displayed at the bottom right of the code editor.

Comment: this is for running the application on WEB mode. If you want to run it on mobile use the android emulator (using android studio).